# How to sort a list and put it in absolute value

Tags: python, list

I have this list that contains positive and negative elements but now I need to sort the list and put it in absolute value, for example:

list[-2,-3,8,-5,1,7]===>list[1,2,3,5,7,8]
Is it clear?
The code:

```
a=5
b=6
c=-3
d=-8

lista = [a,b,c,d]
lista.sort()
lista.reverse()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the  `map` and `abs` functions to accomplish this:

```
In [1]: sorted(map(abs, lista))
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

To do this with the code you wrote, you can

```
# The list defined above
lista = [a,b,c,d]

# Sorted from least to greatest absolute value
sorted_abs_list = sorted(map(abs, lista))

# Sorted from greatest to least absolute value
sorted_abs_list = sorted(map(abs, lista), reverse=True)
```

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a simple example to work off of.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> list[-2,-3,8,-5,1,7]
>>> list = [ i if i > 0 else -i for i in list]
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> list[-2,-3,8,-5,1,7]
>>> list = [ abs(i) for i in list]
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You can replace `-1 * i` with `-i`. Or you can replace `i if i>0 else -i` with `abs(i)`. Also avoid naming your variables `list` or other builtin functions.

Comment: `abs()` is a function that gives the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted([abs(el) for el in lista])
```

Comment: `sorted` can accept a generator expression as argument, so `sorted(abs(el) for el in lista)` works better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort them by their absolute value, but have the list maintain their original values:

```
lista = [-2, -3, 8, -5, 1, 7]

lista.sort(key=lambda x: abs(x))

lista 

Out: [1, -2, -3, -5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [-2, -3, 8, -5, 1, 7]

lista.sort(key=abs)

lista
```

You can try above codes.